# time taken by normal query vs case containing query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-error-1064, dbeaver

what amount of time gets increased when we use case statement in MYSQL query vs without case statement in INSERT QUery ?

Comment: We cannot debug code we cannot see.

Comment: its a question , if we put case in select query time for query execution will increase or decrease ?